# How does a simple java program behave without explicit thread creation?

Tags: java, multithreading

How does a java program behaves in terms of operations without explicit thread creation? Does the whole program execute in a single process? or does it create threads implicitly?
This question crossed my mind while learning about threads and how threads can be useful with GUI interaction as it allows user to interact with the GUI and at the same time allows the program to perform operations behind the scene. So does this mean a simple java program runs a single process, executing each line sequentially without threads usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you explicitly start a new thread either by [instantiating one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html), using an [executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) or resorting to some third party library that does one of the two for you (such as most GUI libraries do so that the UI doesn't block the whole thing, like you said), the whole program runs on a single thread like you said.

There might be non-obvious exceptions (such as using [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html), which resort to a common executor) but this is the general rule.

Comment: I think it is also worth to mention that it is not only Main thread but also other daemon threads like: GC, Finalizer which runs in the background.

Answer (score 0):

In a Java program one can use the following statement to know (or print) the name of the thread the application is running: `System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());`. A simple `PrintHelloWorld` program will show that program runs on a thread named "main". Also, one can use `Thread`'s `toString()` method to get similar info.

**Regarding the threads in a GUI application (e.g., Swing):**

GUI (Graphical User Interface) applications are inherently asynchronous. A user may select a menu item or press a button at any time, and expects that the application will respond promptly. Java Swing and AWT address this issue by creating a separate thread for handling user initiated events and updating the graphical view presented to the user.

The event handling code runs on a special thread known as the event dispatch thread (EDT). Most code that invokes Swing methods also runs on this thread. Most tasks are invocations of event-handling methods, such as `ActionListener.actionPerformed`. Tasks on the event dispatch thread must finish quickly; if they don't, unhandled events backup and the user interface becomes unresponsive or freezes.

Other tasks can be scheduled by the application code, using the static methods `javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater` or `invokeAndWait`. These two methods are used within the Swing application's EDT to execute code asynchronously and synchronously respectively.

One can determine whether the code of a GUI application is running on the event dispatch thread by invoking the static method `SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread`.